# React: In a map loop, how do I break the table row after four columns have been printed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How do I print the following table structure with a list of data?
Let's suppose I have the following list of cities.

```
cities = ['San Fransisco', 'Mumbai', 'Belarus', 'Kathmandu', 'Jakarta', 'Manila', 'Copenhagen', 'Tehran', 'Khartoum', 'Jeddah']
```

I need to break the table row after every four columns have been printed, as follows:

```
<tr>
  <td>San Fransisco</td>
  <td>Mumbai</td>
  <td>Belarus</td>
  <td>Kathmandu</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Jakarta</td>
  <td>Manila</td>
  <td>Copenhagen</td>
  <td>Tehran</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Khartoum</td>
  <td>Jeddah</td>
</tr>
```

Here's what I tried:

```
<table className="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Delivery Location</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    {cities && cities.map((zone, i) => { return (
       {(i % 4 === 0) ? <tr key={i}> : null }
         <td>{zone.name}</td>
       {(i % 4 === 0) ? </tr> : null }
    )})}

  </tbody>
</table>
```

But my IDE shows multiple syntax errors. I also tried adding a wrapping div around the code but I'm still getting the errors.

Comment: May I know why you wanna split 4 no's of data into row? What I am thinking is, we can have list cities rendered first and the we can make them visible in 4 column layout easily without table.

Comment: I want to accomodate four cities in 4 columns in a table row and move on to the next one, i.e. on `index 4` and `index 8` the loop should print <tr> and </tr>. How do you mean we render the cities first and make them visible in 4-column layout with table?

Comment: To make it easier for you to understand, consider bootstrap columns. You can have a some thing like this <div class="row">cities.map((zone, i) => { return (<div className="col-md-3">{zone.name}</div>)}</div>

Comment: Yes, I came across that idea. But in this particular case, I must implement table columns and not make use of bootstrap grid.

Comment: Could be wrong but I think you need additional "return ()" around your html with the <tr>s.

Comment: I tried adding return multiple in ways, without success. It'd be helpful if you'd add an answer with your approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reduce the arrays into an array of arrays each having 4 elements and then have a nested map structure like

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        rcities: ['San Fransisco', 'Mumbai', 'Belarus', 'Kathmandu', 'Jakarta', 'Manila', 'Copenhagen', 'Tehran', 'Khartoum', 'Jeddah']
    }
    componentDidMount() {
  
const size = 4;
var rcities = [...this.state.rcities];
const res = rcities.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
  if ( !(i % size)  ) {    // if index is 0 or can be divided by the `size`...
    acc.push(rcities.slice(i, i + size));   // ..push a chunk of the original array to the accumulator
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

    this.setState({cities: res})
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.cities)
        return (
            <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Delivery Location</th>
                <th>a</th>
                <th>b</th>
                <th>c</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

              {this.state.cities && this.state.cities.map((zone, i) => { return (
                 <tr key={i}>
                    {zone.map((city, index) => {
                    return    <td key={index}>{city}</td>
                    })}
                 </tr>
                 
                 )})}
          
            </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```